# WPF FlowDocument : Resizing Image by Dragging "Grab Points"?

Tags: wpf, image, resize, flowdocument

Is there a built-in control that allows the user to grab the drag points on the corners and/or sides to resize an `Image` in a `FlowDocument`?  It's common functionality, but I can't find it or any reference on how to implement it.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you can re-size IN a FlowDocument.   You could apply a click event that brings up the image in a separate sizable image viewer.

Comment: That would explain why I can't find a reference.... :-)

Comment: You can try with BlockUIContainer and host as sizable image viewer but I would be (pleasantly) surprised if the FlowDocument could deal with a dynamic layout.

Comment: `host as sizable image viewer` - what do you mean?